# Indentation in python major mode

Tags: indentation, python

I am in a .py file with python major mode (syntax highlighting is working).  I am trying to just use the TAB key to indent a code section. Nothing happens.

Now it would be nice for emacs to do intelligent formatting. I am not even asking that! Just asking it to move text (code) over whatever the predefined number of spaces.

I can not paste the code.  The disable aggressive python indentation has been added but it did not work.

At this point, I just want a way to "indent no matter what" ..

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code for which it is doing nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if the syntax on previous lines is incorrect emacs doesn't indent. One common case is a missing colon, e.g. at the end of an if statement.

Alternatively, your current syntax is correct and adding a tab would break the code, which is why emacs isn't letting you do it.

You could always use spaces.

Comment: hmm. I am able to copy and paste all of the code into ipython and run it..

Comment: @javadb a sample of your code, or other code that reproduces the problem, would be vey helpful. One possibility: It makes sense that your code, unindented, runs in iPython. Indentation would break it, which is why emacs isn't letting you do it.

Answer (score 0):

With python-mode.el, which needs to be installed explicitly, customize `py-tab-indents-region-p` to `t` - default is nil.

Note, in case indent is already at outmost reasonable level, first TAB will do nothing, following TAB will shift region cycling possible indents.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have access to install packages on this machine.  I may suggest to the sysadmin in the end if there were no zero-impact solutions.